# Unable to infer base url, error with Swagger UI

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

i am using swagger to do docs api and got error **Unable to infer base url**, i tried some previous solutions on stackoverflow but not working, someone help me.
I use swagger 2.7.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**SwaggerConfig:**

```
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
     @Bean
     public Docket apiDocket() {
         return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                 .select()
                 .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.javaspring.blogapi"))
                 .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                 .build();
     }
}
```

**SecurityConfig:**

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->
                 Auth
                         .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**",
                                 "/v2/api-docs",
                                 "/v3/api-docs",
                                 "/v3/api-docs/**",
                                 "/swagger-resources",
                                 "/swagger-resources/**",
                                 "/configuration/ui",
                                 "/configuration/security",
                                 "/swagger-ui/**",
                                 "/webjars/**",
                                 "/swagger-ui.html").permitAll()
```

**One of the controllers:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/users")
public class UserController {
     @Autowired
     private UserService userService;

     @GetMapping("/{username}")
     public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUser(@PathVariable String username){
         return ResponseEntity.ok().body(userService.findByUsername(username));
     }
```

I tried typing **http://localhost:8080/** in the input when it said **Unable to infer base url** but it didn't solve the problem.

Specific notice:
Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually:

Answer (score 0):

Add `.pathMapping("/")` after build() in swagger config.

And add this property in application.properties :

```
spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER
```